# How to specify CustomScrollView to scroll to a Sliver Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

First, I have a CustomScrollView that has several SilverGrids as children.

```
CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            _grid1(),
            _grid2(),
            _grid3(),
          ],
        )
```

Then I have a button that controls the CustomScrollView to scroll to just show Grid2 when pressed

```
 RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
            _scrollController.animateTo( _getGrid2Offset(),
                duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.linear);
          },)
```

But I don't know how to calculate the position of Grid2 relative to CustomScrollView

Comment: Hi do you have any solution?

Comment: @ch271828n Sorry, there is too little information, then I gave up. Now a year has passed, I don't know what's going on.

Comment: Oh so sad :(...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is you can't (right now) to calculate this value directly.
You will have to calculate the offset yourself which will cover most of the basic cases. If you have a list of items with the same height then you can do a simple

```dart
var offset = index * height + somethingElse
```

and give this value to the widget. If your case is more complex then you should create a function to calculate it from all the factors like size,type,margin,padding.